# Efficiently updating multiple rows in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table called Funds I want to update each row of column Amount by Amount+2 for each ClientId column.

The selection criteria is every ClientId from table BetsPlaced which could contain multiple rows for one ClientId. When I run the following sql the Funds table for each ClientId is updated but only once. How do I formulate the sql so each transaction is committed as it happens?

For example, ClientId 22133 Amount is set at £500 in the Funds table.

There are 10 rows in the BetsPlaced table for ClientId 22133, a row represents Amount 2 so the update should set Amount to Amount+2 but do it 10 times and set Amount to £520.

```
update Funds 
set    Amount=Amount+2, 
       LastUpdated=now() 
where  ClientId in (
           select x.ClientId from (
               select b.ClientId from betsplaced b
           ) as x
        );
```

Apologies if any of this is unclear, happy to explain further. I've got round it by running a while loop for all rows in BetsPlaced but it's slow and I'd hope some smart sql code can run it much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
update Funds F INNER JOIN
(SELECT ClientID, COUNT(ClientID) NumberTimes FROM BetsPlaced GROUP BY ClientID) B ON B.ClientID = F.ClientID
 set Amount=Amount+(2 * B.NumberTimes), LastUpdated=now();
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic Sir !! I am very grateful. It runs in about the same time as it takes me to press the button ! Thank you

Comment: Happy to help. Cheers!  I'm not a sir though  ;)

Comment: Hi - I wonder if i could trouble you again. I have a build up of values that I want to show to the nearest 1000 until it gets to the next thousand. So a value of 1800 should default to 1000, so would 1999 but 2001, 2022, 2100 should default to 2000. When I use the round command with -3 it pushes it upwards with anything above 500. The sql I'm running is in the next comment:

Comment: Select round(count(*)*2*(select (100-CommissionRate)/100 from Events where EventId=10049)+(select BHFundAmount from Events where EventId=10049)+(select RolloverFromAmount*(select (100-CommissionRate)/100 from Events where EventId=10049) from Events where EventId=10049),-3) as countVal FROM BetsPlaced where EventId=10049. The values will steadily increase as rows are added to BetsPlaced. How do I keep it rounded down ? Thanks

Comment: Regarding the truncation, if you convert the result to an integer then divide it by 1000 and multiply it by 1000, that will guarantee to always round down. E.g. (5999/1000) * 1000 = 5 * 1000 = 5000. Note, however, that if the number is less than 1000, the result is always 0. Another thing, your query is also a bit overcomplicated - you are pulling the same record from the events table (where eventid = 10049) several times to retrieve different fields. What you need is to do a join between the Events and BetsPlaced tables and then filter once for the EventId. See below comment.

Comment: Select CONVERT(int, (count(B.EventId) * 2 * (100-E.CommissionRate)/100 +
BHFundAmount + (RolloverFromAmount * (100-E.CommissionRate)/100))/1000) * 1000 as countVal FROM BetsPlaced B
INNER JOIN Events E ON E.EventId  = B.EventId
where E.EventId=10049
GROUP BY E.EventID, E.CommissionRate, E.BHFundAmount, E.RolloverFromAmount

Comment: Hi - thanks for this, unfortunately I'm getting an error when running your improved code. If I take the convert out I get the right amounts as per table contents which I'm happy with but can't get convert or cast to round down. Would you mind taking another look ? Thanks